# Form validation does not triggered after data is loaded

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms, validation

I have a function that calculates form completion percentage.

When editing an existing record, data is loaded and rendered but the validation does not kick in.
If I edit data in one of the inputs then it gets triggered and start working.

```
<div ng-form="dtform" class="container-fluid form-horizontal" ng-cloak>
    <fieldset ng-form="requestor_tab"> ... </fieldset>
    <fieldset ng-form="some_tab"> ... </fieldset>
</div>
```

Events that trigger the function

```
$scope.$watch("data", () => { calculateCompleted(); }, true);
$scope.$watch("dtform.$valid", () => calculateCompleted());
```

Calculate function:

```
let calculateCompleted = () => {
    let errors = 0; 
    let success = 0;
    settings.tabs.forEach(tab => {

        // Here is the problem: $scope.dtform[tab].$$success is undefined.
        if ($scope.dtform && $scope.dtform[tab] && $scope.dtform[tab].$$success && $scope.dtform[tab].$$success.required)
            success += $scope.dtform[tab].$$success.required.length;
    });
    // some math logic
    return percentage;
};
```

It appears that `$scope.dtform[tab].$$success` is undefined when this function is run but when I check the value in console it is defined and has a value.

It seems that I am missing an additional trigger, can someone advise what trigger could this be?

Thanks

Edit: 
I know it can be solved by triggering this function from the template 
`<div ng-hide="checkCompetion()"></div>`
but I was wondering if there is a more elegant solution

Answer (score 0):

If none of the fields are valid then it may not have any `tab` objects defined.

**Try adding this**:

```
if($scope.dtform.hasOwnProperty(tab)){
```

**To this**:

```
settings.tabs.forEach(tab => {

    // Check if it works adding it here.
    if($scope.dtform.hasOwnProperty(tab)){


        if ($scope.dtform && $scope.dtform[tab] && $scope.dtform[tab].$$success && $scope.dtform[tab].$$success.required)
            success += $scope.dtform[tab].$$success.required.length;


    }

});
```

Comment: This check is already covered `if( ... && $scope.dtform[tab] && ...`